# Getting wall time limit in bjobs

Tags: platform-lsf

I'm writing a script that collect job information.  I would like to get the wall time limit for each pending job (as specified with bsub -W) using bjobs.  I can get information such as the number of cpus using a command like:

```
bjobs -u all -p -o 'jobid user min_req_proc'
```

But I can't find any keyword that will give me wall time.  Does such a method exist?  Right now I have to run bjobs -l for every job to get that information, which is very slow.

Comment: Have you tried `runtimelimit` -- `bjobs -u all -p -o 'jobid user runtimelimit'`

Comment: What is that bjobs command, btw?

Comment: Holy smokes, runtimelimit did it!  I can't find that in the official bjobs manual.  Where can I get a complete list of the available keywords?

Comment: I found it here: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSWRJV_10.1.0/lsf_command_ref/bjobs.o.1.html -- it's under the `-o` option.  I can write an answer with the link.

Answer (score 1):

`runtimelimit` is `-o` the keyword you're looking for.  You can find a full list of supported keywords here:

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSWRJV_10.1.0/lsf_command_ref/bjobs.o.1.html

Unfortunately the table doesn't tell you exactly which `bsub` options they map to.